# One is uiautomator to inspect the element and What will other alternate solution to inspect the element of phone

Tags: java, appium

[enter image description here][1]I am unable to get the element of Forgerox app and giving the error UI hierarchy as attached screenshot. 
This test page is randomly changing. So i am unable to locate the elements Please tell me what will be another solution for that

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Please give some more information, and don't add explanation in screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your problem but the alternate solution to uiautomator is [Appium Inspector](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-inspector/)

Comment: to capture the locator values from 2 factor authentication

Comment: but unable to capture.It is resetting your 2 factor authentication account